# listbox dragdrop in wpf

Tags: wpf, listview, drag-and-drop

I am currently porting a windows forms application to wpf. There is a listbox with filenames in it. It should be possible to drag (multiple) items to the windows explorer. 
This was easy in with the old windows form, but I can't find a way how this can be done in wpf.

This was the code I used with windows forms:

```
void listView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = GetSelection();
    if (files != null)
    {
        DoDragDrop(new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, files), DragDropEffects.Copy );  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok... I found a solution for my Problem, based on [this tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html):

```
    private void List_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Store the mouse position
        startPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
    }

    private void List_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the current mouse position
        Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
        Vector diff = startPoint - mousePos;

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
            Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance &&
            Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
        {
            if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            string[] files = GetSelection();
            string dataFormat = DataFormats.FileDrop;
            DataObject dataObject = new DataObject(dataFormat, files);
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listView1, dataObject, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out Bea Stollnitz' blog for a thorough implementation of drag and drop in WPF.

[Bea Stollnitz - How can I drag and drop items between data bound ItemsControls?](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53)

Answer (score 1):

```
try this code that help u to solve your problem



public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<string> file = new List<string>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            file.Add(@"D:\file1.txt");
            file.Add(@"D:\folder1");
            file.Add(@"D:\folder2");
            file.Add(@"D:\folder3");
            lstTest.DataContext = file;
        }


        private Point start;
        private void lstTest_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.start = e.GetPosition(null);
        }

        private void lstTest_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point mpos = e.GetPosition(null);
            Vector diff = this.start - mpos;
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance && Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
            {
                if (this.lstTest.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                string[] Files = new string[file.Count] ;
                for (int i = 0; i < file.Count; i++)
                {
                    Files[i] = file[i];
                }
                string dataFormat = DataFormats.FileDrop;
                DataObject dataObject = new DataObject(dataFormat, (lstTest.SelectedItems.Cast<string>()).ToArray<string>());
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, dataObject, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you checked ( checkbox ) the multiple selection option

Comment: the multiple selection is not the problem, the code obove shows the way I've done the drag and drop in WIN Forms, I want to know how this works with WPF